# Adal4J org.xml.sax.SAXParseException

Tags: xml, mule, azure-active-directory, adal4j

My Mule application was working fine and all of a sudden i started getting the below exception.

Open quote is expected for attribute "classId" associated with an  element type  "object".
ERROR 2017-09-20 21:12:22,455 [pool-11-thread-1] com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext: [Correlation ID: xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxx] Request to acquire token failed.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Open quote is expected for attribute "classId" associated with an  element type  "object".

Any help would help.

Comment: We need more info to debug this, can you capture a network trace of the error and update the question with the error response from `login.microsoftonline.com`. Also, adding some code would be super helpful.

Comment: Based on the [SAXParseException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/SAXParseException.html), it seems the SDK failed to parse the response Azure AD. First please check whether the response is returned successfully  as  @DanielDobalian mentioned.  If yes, please also check whether the SDK have published the latest version and check whether it is helpful.

Comment: @vejay2k Any update for this issue?

Comment: Thanks, Everyone. It looks like the response from Azure is not successful. I am looking into the response and found the response as bad request.